# RegExp: Matching everything except regex values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to achieve is to match every single word and character, except `two, Two, TWO` words. This code is part of a form validation, where `two, Two, TWO` are the answers for the captcha question:

```
//if(! event.target.validity.valid) {
if(! event.target.validity.valid && input.value === /(^(?!two$|Two$|TWO$).*)/gm) {
  elem.className = 'error';
  parentDiv.className += ' error-input';
  elem.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Unfortunately this is not working.

**UPDATE:**

I tried all regex here and finally the loop also, but still not working. I copying here the entire function to have a more view what's going on:

```
var lang = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');

(function() {
  function field(name, langif, langelse) {

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.style.display = 'none';

    var input = document.getElementById(name);
    var parentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName(name)[0];
    input.parentNode.appendChild(elem);

    // Turning on when error is presented
    input.addEventListener('invalid', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(!event.target.validity.valid && name !== 'captcha') {
        elem.className = 'error';
        parentDiv.className += ' error-input';
        elem.style.display = 'block';
      };
      if(!event.target.validity.valid && name === 'captcha' && input.value === input.value.match(/(^(?!kettő$|ketto$|Kettő$|Ketto$|KETTŐ$|KETTO$|two$|Two$|TWO$).*)/gm)[0]) {
        elem.className = 'error-captcha';
        parentDiv.className += ' error-input-captcha';
        elem.style.display = 'block';
      };
      if(!event.target.validity.valid && lang === 'hu-HU') {
        elem.textContent = langif;
      } else {
        elem.textContent = langelse;
      };
    });

    // Turning off when error is not presented
    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      if(elem.style.display === 'block') {
        elem.className = '';
        parentDiv.classList.remove('error-input');
        elem.style.display = 'none';
      };
    });

    return;
  };

  // Init function
  field('firstname', 'A keresztnév kötelező és/vagy számokat tartalmazott.', 'Firstname is required and/or the field had numbers.');
  field('surname', 'A vezetéknév kötelező és/vagy számokat tartalmazott.', 'Surname is required and/or the field had numbers.');
  field('email', 'Email cím kötelező. Ajánlott formátum: valami@domain.hu', 'Email address is required. Recommended format: something@domain.com');
  field('message', 'Üzenet mező kitöltése kötelező.', 'Message is required.');
  field('captcha', 'Captcha kitöltése kötelező.', 'Captcha is required.');

})();
```

Expected behaviour: if input field is empty, than throw error. if input field is not matching the described captcha answers, than throw error. Now only works if the input field is empty.

**UPDATE 2:**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/ja77k6ca/2/

Only with relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/ja77k6ca/8/

Comment: Try `if(!event.target.validity.valid && !/^(?:two|Two|TWO)$/m.test(input.value))`

Comment: I included the entire function to have more view what's going on. Unfortunately this doesn't worked.

Comment: I added a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/ja77k6ca/2

Comment: The relevant portion of your code isn't running when I submit the form, I'm getting an error from JSFiddle...

Comment: `action=""` updated to `action="/"` https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/ja77k6ca/8/ BTW if it's sending the message and the captcha answer is not met, there is problem with the regex. It should only send the post request when the correct captcha entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
var captchaAnswers = {'two': true, 'Two': true, 'TWO': true};

if(!event.target.validity.valid && !(input.value in captchaAnswers)) {
    ...
};
```

---

EDIT:
Your actual issue is coming from the invalid event not being fired on the input when the field is not empty. To make it fire the event you should use the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) attribute on the input element.

See an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ja77k6ca/9/).

Comment: I included the entire function to have more view what's going on. Unfortunately this doesn't worked.

Comment: @Lanti What isn't working? Do you get an error or is that block of code never hit?

Comment: It supposed to be work in the following fashion: if input field is empty, than throw error. if input field is not matching the described captcha answers, than throw error. Now only works if the input field is empty.

Comment: I also updated my question with the actual code. I implemented regex. Or maybe the loop of array is faster?

Comment: Thank You! Yes, the pattern attribute is the easiest solution. But isn't it more easier to crack it for the spammer robots? There is a validation on the server side, which containing the same captcha words. However I wanted to validate this on the client side also, to give a feedback to the user before refreshing the page. That's why I tried to enter the captcha answers in the client-side javascript function. I think embedding these words in to the html is the most easiest way for the spammer robots to crack it. But if there's no another way to doing this...

Comment: Rethinking this: is there a way to write the pattern attribute to the DOM from my javascript function? I can read the content of `<html lang="">` so maybe there's a way to write the pattern into captcha's input field. Maybe some spammer robots only reading the actual HTML file, not the DOM, when scanning the page for captcha answers.

Comment: @Lanti If you really want to provide client side validation and stay protected from most bots you should hash the possible captcha answers (e.g MD5 or SHA1), then hash the user-submitted captcha answer and compare it to the possible values. You won't be able to use the `invalid` event listener any more though, only a listener for the form submit event.

Comment: Or maybe I should take a look at AJAX? The captcha answer already validated on the server side, so I think the best solution was to get the answer from the server without submitting the entire form. Using AJAX only for the captcha answer.

Answer (score 1):

This `if` statement is trying to see if `input.value`, **a string**,  is equal to `/(^(?!two$|Two$|TWO$).*)/gm`, a **regular expression**.

They are of different types, so they will never be equal.

You should instead use [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match_) to see if `input.value` matches the regular expression.

This should give you the desired result:

```
// check to see if calling "match" on the
// regular expression returns the user input

if(! event.target.validity.valid && input.value === input.value.match(/(^(?!two$|Two$|TWO$).*)/gm)[0]) {
  elem.className = 'error';
  parentDiv.className += ' error-input';
  elem.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Comment: I included the entire function to have more view what's going on. Unfortunately this doesn't worked.

Comment: I'm getting errors for missing resources, please clean your JS Fiddle up so as only to include the relevant portions.

Comment: I removed the html tag lang check variable. Is there still missing resources error? Can you describe your error output?

Comment: I'm not going to fill out your entire form in order to debug, can you prefill or only include the relevant inputs?

Comment: This is the fiddle only with the relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/ja77k6ca/7/